# Set value to a realm object

Tags: android, realm

I have following class

```
public class Student extends RealmObject{
private int studentID;
private String studentName;

// getters and setters here

}
```

Then I try to set a value to a already created student object

```
student.setStudentName("Peter");
```

Then I get following error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mutable method call during read
>   transaction.

In order to overcome this I have to do it as follows

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(this);
realm.beginTransaction();
student.setStudentName("Peter");
realm.commitTransaction();
```

I don't want to persist this change in the database. How can I just set/change a value to an realm object variable without always persisting it to the database?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to modify the object in a non-persisted manner, you need an unmanaged copy of it.

You can create a copy using `realm.copyFromRealm(RealmObject realmObject);` method.

Answer (score 4):

When you are using `Realm.createObject()`, the object is added to the Realm and it only works within a write transaction. You can cancel a transaction and thereby discard the object.

Moreover, you can use your model class as a standalone class and create objects in memory (see http://realm.io/docs/java/0.80.0/#creating-objects for details). If you need to persist the objects, you can use the `Realm.copyToRealm()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create a new Model.  And your new model should implement `RealmModel`.

```
public class StudentRM extends RealmModel{
private int studentID;
private String studentName;

// Constructors here
// getters and setters here

}
```

Now you can do this.

```
studentRm.setStudentName("Peter"); //Setting Vale Or
studentRm.addAll(student); //Add all value from DB
studentRm.setStudentName("Jhon"); //It won't change DB anymore
studentRm.getStudentName(); // "Jhon"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `realm.cancelTransaction();`, instead of `realm.commitTransaction();`